# How to build Erlang v24 for couchdb?

Tags: erlang, couchdb, yocto, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to compile erlang 24 in yocto build system, the recommended version for CouchDB, but it fails. I'm using meta-erlang layer.

This is the error I am getting:

```
| configure: WARNING: No GLU headers found, wx will NOT be usable
| configure: WARNING:
|         wxWidgets must be installed on your system.
|
|         Please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
|         where wxWidgets libraries are installed (returned by
|         'wx-config --libs' or 'wx-config --static --libs' command)
|         is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent variable and
|         wxWidgets version is 3.0.2 or above.
|
| *********************************************************************
| **********************  APPLICATIONS DISABLED  **********************
| *********************************************************************
|
| jinterface     : Java compiler disabled by user
| observer       : User gave --without-observer option
| odbc           : User gave --without-odbc option
|
| *********************************************************************
| *********************************************************************
| **********************  APPLICATIONS INFORMATION  *******************
| *********************************************************************
|
| wx             : No GLU headers found, wx will NOT be usable
| wxWidgets was not compiled with --enable-webview or wxWebView developer package is not installed, wxWebView will NOT be available
|
|         wxWidgets must be installed on your system.
|
|         Please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
|         where wxWidgets libraries are installed (returned by
|         'wx-config --libs' or 'wx-config --static --libs' command)
|         is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent variable and
|         wxWidgets version is 3.0.2 or above.
|
| *********************************************************************
| *********************************************************************
| **********************  DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION  ******************
| *********************************************************************
|
| documentation  :
|                  xsltproc is missing.
|                  fop is missing.
|                  xmllint is missing.
|                  The documentation cannot be built.
|
| | *********************************************************************
| sed: can't read /mnt/project/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-ino-linux-musleabi/erlang/25.3.2.8/git/erts/arm-ino-linux-musleabi-gnu/config.h: No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
```

Strange that the recipe for erlang does not contain wxWidgets dependenncie.
What am I missing here showuld I add wxwidgets-native to my recipe?

Answer (score 2):

There are no errors in that printout, only warnings. If you do not need any of the functionality listed you can continue building and ignore the warnings. If you need some part of it, then check the install guide for erlang on erlang.org to see which dependencies are needed.

Comment: You are right about that. However config.h was never created after autoconf finished. I edited my answer to include the build break error. Initially I thought these were breaking changes.

Comment: Nothing in the Erlang/OTP build system should sed into config.h, so probably meta-erlang is doing that. I'm not familiar with how that works, so you should probably go and ask them, or wait for someone that migt knows to wander by here.